# Not able to retrieve strongAuthenticationEmailAddress

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am unable to store or retrieve the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress, needed to verify whether the verification email used for pwd reset is the same as originally entered at setup.

In the signup journey, my AAD-UserWriteUsingUserId TP includes writing the email address (the signup includes email verification):

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingUserId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="SomeDefaultDisplayNameValue" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />       
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

I am attempting to retrieve it later in my AAD-UserReadUsingUserId which is invoked in the validation step invoked as part of pwd reset:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signinName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <!-- Optional claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />          
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />           
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
        <!--OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailAndStrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" /-->                        
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>          
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

However, the claims collection does not include the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress, presumably because it is null. (I get the collection in the token issued at the end of the journey if I comment out the assertion comparing thw two email addresses). What am I doing wrong?

Updated TPs (called from step 1 of PwdReset):

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserId">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using user id and address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">User authentication email and provided email address do not match.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signinName" Required="true" />
        <!--OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingUserId" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signinName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
        <!-- Optional claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />            
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

RP (both email and strongAuthenticationEmailAddress cause errors on policy load:

```
  <RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **AAD-UserReadUsingUserId** technical profile, you are attempting to read the **email** property (not the **strongAuthenticationEmailAddress** property) of the **user** object to the **strongAuthenticationEmailAddress** claim.

You must remove the `PartnerClaimType` attribute of the `OutputClaim` element:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. It is still not working for me. Is there any way to see whether strongAuthenticationEmailAddress is persisted? I modified my PwdRest policy as follows:

Comment: Thanks Chris. It is still not working for me. Is there any way to see whether strongAuthenticationEmailAddress (SAEA) is persisted? I modified my PwdRest policy to include that claim in the eventual JWT token. That policy uses LocalAcountDiscoveryUsingUserId as its first step. That TP in turns has the SEAE as OutputClaim. The validation TP it calls (AAD-UserReadUsingUserId) also has that output claim (without any PartnerClaim references in either case). Now loading my PwdRest policy fails with error that SAEA is the output claim but it is not an output claim in any of the steps of the journey.

Comment: Hi @Marc. Can you please add the latest mods for the different TPs to the above question?

Comment: Chris, I added these to my original question.